# Facebook game invitable friends search box

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-invite-friends

In the facebook docs for invitable friends, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.3 they recommended

"Even though the friend list provided by the invitable friends API is a ranked list sorted by relevance to the current player, it is a good idea to build a search box into your multi-friend selector. This way you will ensure that your players who have a big list of invitable friends can find the right friend they want to invite into your game."

However, there is no search API for invitable friends. Do they expect us to make a call to invitable friends with limit = 5000 and perform search on the client side? If so, what's the point of providing the paging parameters?

Comment: Yes, they expect you to implement that search functionality client-side. And you don’t have to go to an extreme like 5000 friends – even for a list of “just” 100 or 50 friends your users might appreciate a simple way to search by just starting to type characters, in the same way as is possible directly on Facebook.